# Counting Characters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the occurrences of certain character within a range. I.E. If I have several cells with words in them I want to count the number of times Capital letter "A" appears.

The most common answer I find (even on this site) is

```
   =SUM(LEN(F59:F73)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F59:F73,"A","")))
```

This particular formula only seems to count the first cell in the range and no others. Why is this happening when it seems to be quite the universal answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to array enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, **or** change the `SUM` to be a `SUMPRODUCT` to force array calculation without having to array enter the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(F59:F73)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F59:F73,"A","")))
```