# find occurrence of character in a range of cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this range and content in Excel

```
A1 B1 C1

bs ss sm
```

I want to be able to count the occurrence of "s" within this range. If I use countif,

```
=COUNTIF(A1:C1,"*s*")
```

the result will be 3, where I want it to be 4. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try this `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:C1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:C1,"s","")))`

Comment: This query already has a solution, have you tried searching `SO` **[Counting Characters in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458056/counting-characters-in-excel)**

Answer (score 1):

With latest version of excel-

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:C1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:C1),"s",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Office 2019 already has `TEXTJOIN`.